# Python-Behave, running features in mutliple subdirectories

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

How can I run behave tests with this kind of file structure:

```
+-- features/
     +-- user_page/
     |     +-- user_crud.feature   
     |     +-- user_search.feature 
     +-- customer_page/
     |     +-- customer_crud.feature
     |     +-- customer_search.feature
+-- steps/
     +-- user_page/
     |     +-- user_crud.py
     |     +-- user_search.py
     +-- customer_page/
     |     +-- customer_crud.py
     |     +-- customer_search.py
```

I want to be able to organize features and steps in its proper page. Currently I can run a test 1 folder at a time with steps not having any sub folders.

example:

```
behave /features/user_page/customer_search.feature
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

According to the document of Behave, it seems you have to put your step definition in the steps folder directly unless you wanna touch some of the source code.

In order to `organize features and steps`, I would recommend you use tags. Or if you mean you want to `get better result` by `organize features and steps`, you could try the Junit or JSON formatters